# Installing perception_pcl_unstable in ROS Electric on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: pcl, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I need to install this stack for a university project: https://github.com/tum-vision/dvo/tree/electric#installation, and it is required to install perception_pcl_unstable. I googled it and found this link: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/ but it's no more active so I have really no idea on how to find and install this package. Pcl is already installed in my ROS environment but I guess it's an old version and it lacks some header files, for this reason "rosmake dvo_core" cannot commit. So I'd really appreciate if someone could point me out how to install that library or another version that might work seamlessly! Thanks for the attention!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78156/installing-perception_pcl_unstable-in-ros-electric-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pcl staff is moved from svn to GitHub.
You are searching this: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/electric-unstable-devel

This is really old and I'm sure, the newest pcl version will not work without modifications. If you get any problems, you should take a look in https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/fuerte-unstable-devel

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2013-09-11**:
Hi Michael, thanks for your reply! I'm quite new to ROS so I'm not familiar with the right procedure to get this software working. If I run:
dede@dede-TW9-SW9:~/check$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/electric-unstable-devel
I get this error:
Cloning into electric-unstable-devel...
fatal: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/electric-unstable-devel/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
I'd be very glad if you could tell me the right steps to install this library. Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-11**:
use: git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b electric-unstable-devel